# getting error while compiling a VC++ program using yara librarary yaralib in release mode

Tags: windows, visual-c++, yara

getting error while compiling a VC++ program using yara library libyara in release mode, I see the errors when I compile the code in visual studio in release mode with settings c/C++ ->Code Generation->Runtime Library(Multi-threaded(/MT)). I am using visual studio 2022

- Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_atof
  ...libyara.lib(lexer.c.obj)
  Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_clearerr(lexer.c.obj)
  Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_clearerr(hex_lexer.c.obj)
  LNK2001  unresolved external symbol __imp_read ...OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) 1    [image]